# hover effect on menu bar divider

Tags: html, css

I have a menu bar

- Home
- About Us
- Contact Us

and I've decorated the menu with a symbol like `# Home # About Us # Contact #`.

So, what I want to achieve is when I mouse over an item, the item color will be changed, as well as the symbols beside. For example:

**# Home #** About Us # Contact Us #

# Home **# About Us #** Contact Us #

# Home # About Us **# Contact Us #**

Anyway to achieve this? Prefer not using javascript solution, thanks.

** Updated with HTML markup as requested, just a dummy solution for placing the symbols.

I think most of you have misunderstanding my question, what I wanted is NOT how to hover a list item, I want to **hover the symbols** which are surrounding the item.

```
//html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li># Home </li>
    <li># About Us </li>
    <li># Contact Us #</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

//css
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: If you prefer not to use javascript, you should remove the javascript and jquery tags.

Comment: First search in google if you didn't find anything then ask here.     Search this "how to change color on hover with css" you got lot of answers

Comment: @sandeep check my update on the post. thanks.

Comment: @shinnyx Can you check if my answer helps you.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An seo friendly example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            nav li{
                display: inline-block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #000;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            nav li:hover {
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #FF0000;
            }
            nav li:before, nav li:hover:after, nav li:last-child:after {
                content:" # ";
            }
            nav li:hover + li:before {
                content:"";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

May that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/cLnUW/  .Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>     
     <li><span>#</span> Home </li>     
     <li><span>#</span> About Us </li>     
     <li><span>#</span> Contact Us</li>
     <li><span>#</span></li>        
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {   display: inline-block; }
li:hover {   font-weight: bold; }
li:hover span, li:hover + li span{color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:hover` pseudoselector, along with a before pseudoselector. Eg.

```
.about:hover{
    color:#ff0000;
}
.about:hover:before{
    content:"->";
}
```

The before pseudoselector prepends some content to the element, in this case an arrow.

Comment: Better way to avoid so many classes #navbardiv ul li:hover just my preference and throwing it out so the op is aware :)

Comment: @zomboble Yeah but then all of them have to be the same color, unless you use nth-child, which is not universally supported.

Answer (score 0):

try using css `:hover`

```
​ul li:hover{
  color: black;
  font: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="symb">#</span> about</li>
        <li><span class="symb">#</span> home</li>
    </ul>
</div>

#navBar ul li:hover{
    color: red;
}
span.symb{
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Using an unordered list like so and changing it with the hover pseudoselector

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
#menu ul li a:hover
{
    color:Green;
}
#menu ul li a:hover:before
{
content:"$";
}

#menu ul li a:before
{
content:"#";
}
```

**[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YTzba/1/)**
​

Comment: @shinnyx Where does it not help you , can you tell me what you need exactly?

Comment: It did gave me the inspiration for my final answer tough :)

Answer (score -1):

Demo solution : http://jsfiddle.net/PBrkX/

The below code uses sample html to show how hover works:

```
 <span id='home_sym'> # Home </span>
    <span id='about_sym'> # About Us </span> 
   <span id='contact_sym'> # Contact Us </span>

  css :

  #home_sym:hover{
       background-color: required color;
       font-weight: bold;
       /* add anyother css required when hover */
   }

   #about_sym:hover{
       background-color: required color;
       font-weight: bold;
       /* add anyother css required when hover */
   }

    #contact_sym:hover{
       background-color: required color;
       font-weight: bold;
       /* add anyother css required when hover */
   }
```